# Use custom file names for iOS launch images

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to define my own naming convention for iOS app splash/launch images as I can with Icon files (e.g. via an Info.plist entry), or must I stick to the `...@2x.png` and `...-568h@2x.png` naming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the root name (the “Default” bit) with the  [UILaunchImageFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW24) key, which has been available since iOS 3.2, but in that case the suffixes—`@2x`, `-568h@2x`, etc.—are still fixed. To supply a set of arbitrary images, you can use the [UILaunchImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW28) array, but be advised that that API is iOS 7-only.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an Asset Catalog (new in XCode5), you can use whatever file naming convention you like.  The Asset Catalog takes care of mapping a logical name for an image resource to a set of files on disk.

Comment: Good to know, but stuck with 4.6 for now.